# WAMP httpd.config redirect

Tags: php, apache, wamp, httpd.conf

I'm using wamp on localhost at `c:\wamp\www\`.
The project located under: `c:\wamp\www\MyProj\public` (root).
In `file1.php` (located in root) I have a link to some fake url (/services/.....).
I'm trying to redirect that url to other file `service_router.php` (in the same direction as file1.php).

I'm doing that in httpd.config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 127.0.0.1  
    DocumentRoot c:\wamp\www\
    <Directory "c:\wamp\www\">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/MyProj/public/services/*
    RewriteRule . /MyProj/public/service_router.php

</VirtualHost>
```

But my WAMP refuses to restart.
What's wrong with my configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I make a few suggestions.

If you want to use Virtual Hosts, and I consider that a very good idea. You need first to make sure that localhost still works and secondly it is a good idea to move you actual projects out of the `\wamp\` folder structure.

So this would be a good starting point for your first ( of many ) VHOSTS

First create a new folder structure somewhere on any of your drives for example

```
C:\websites\project1\www
```

Now copy your project to the www folder.

Now setup the vhosts

```
# must be first VHOST so the that localhost and the wamp menu page still work
# Also makes this the default site so any randon hacks on your ip address
# will come here and hopefully be rejected because it only 'Allows' access 
# from this machine ( see Allow Deny )
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost

    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1 
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/project1/www"
    ServerName project1.dev
    ServerAlias www.dqsc.old
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    <Directory "C:/websites/project1/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Unless you actually want to make this site available to the World** can I suggest that you dont use `Allow from all`.

Try using or the second Allow line if you want to see your site from any machine on your internal network, just use the first 3 of the 4 quartiles of your ip address and it will allow access from any ip starting with those 3 quartiles.

```
Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1 
   Allow from 192.168.0
```

Now you need to amend your `HOSTS` file so that windows knows about your new domain name.

Edit `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the new site name `project1.dev` like so, you will have to launch your editor 'Run as Administrator' as this file is protected by windows :-

```
127.0.0.1 project1.dev
```

Now restart the "DNS Client" service to refresh the windows dns cache so it see's your new domain name. Start a command window, again "Run as Administrator".

```
net stop "DNS Client"
net start "DNS Client"
```

You should now be able to enter `http://project1.dev` in a browser and it will find you new site.

Finally, once you test that your site is working, put the url rewrite coding in a `.htaccess` file in the root of your new project.

```
C:\websites\www\project1\.htaccess
```