# Redirect from one url to another url using wamp

Tags: php, drupal, wampserver, redirect

I am using the following code:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80 >

     ServerName localhost/Stack
     Redirect  / https://www.examplesite.com 
  </VirtualHost>
```

What is happening is that whenever I am typing `localhost/Stack` its redirecting to
`/www.examplesite.comStack`. Why is this happening?

What I want to do is that when I go to `examplesite/dob` it should be redirected to   `examplesite/d_o_b`. The server I am using is wamp. d_o_b is a drupal site.

Comment: Why redirect, why not just setup a proper virtual host definition for the site you want to use? It will work properly then as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666482/wamp-httpd-config-redirect/22684812#22684812

Comment: `ServerName localhost/Stack` – that is not a valid server name, server names don’t contain slashes.